# Trouble Inserting Sub Entites Using Bulk Insert

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, bulkinsert

I'm trying to insert a list of entities and their sub entities using Bulk Insert. Below is a snippet of the code:

```
           ctx.BulkInsert<Entity>(list.Select(x => new Entity
                {
                    Value = x.Value,
                    IsActive = x.IsActive,
                    SubEntities = new Collection<SubEntity>(x.SubEntities.Select(y => new SubEntity {Key = y.Key, Value = y.Value}).ToList())
            }));
```

There's also an option for including The entity or entity Id in the subentity, but since it's already in the creation for the Entity itself it shouldn't need that right? However it's not creating any of the subentities with the entity itself. Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As far as I know BulkInsert does not support inserting children with it at this time.  You may want to consider inserting using merge tables and raw SQL commands instead of attempting to do this with entity framework though.  While I'm a big proponent of EF, a task like this is like trying to use a hammer on a screw - it'll work, but what is there to be gained for this single task?

Comment: You should insert main items via `ctx.AddRange` and then use `BulkInsert` for their subItems with assigned `parentId`s

Comment: I was able to insert the items via Add Range, thanks guys :)